# Undefined method in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm a beginner in Ruby and I'm doing a really easy "game".

My problem is that I want to test if the user press `1` then roll some dices but I can't use my method. Please refer to the code below for more details:

```
class Player
#i have some methods but it work
end

class Game
     tot = 0
        def rollDice
            tot = 0
            puts "You roll the dices"
            d1 = rand(1..6)
            puts "Dice 1: #{d1}"
            d2 = rand(1..6)
            puts "Dice 2: #{d2}"
            d3 = rand(1..6)
            puts "Dice #{d3}"
            tot = d1 + d2 + d3
            puts "Your score is  #{tot}"
            return tot
        end 

    #some puts but not important for the coding 

    puts "Press 1 to play or 2 to leave"
    value = gets.chomp
        if value == "1"
            s1 = rollDice
            puts "Why it doesnt work :C #{s1}"

    #[i have a player class but its not important for the moment]
            #player1 = Joueur.new(j1)
            #player2 = Joueur.new(j2)

            #player1.score
            #player2.score
        elsif value== "2"
            exit
        end
end
```

But i have the undefined method error for my method rollDice
thank you really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does work. However, your `rollDice` definition is indented (and you have a second `tot=0` call), so I guess you actually defined it in something else (a class?), which is at the time of writing not included in your posted code sample.

Btw, following conventions/style guides I would suggest you to rename `rollDice` into `roll_dice`.

The code I tested successfully is this one:

```
def rollDice
    tot = 0
    puts "You roll the dices"
    d1 = rand(1..6)
    puts "Dice 1: #{d1}"
    d2 = rand(1..6)
    puts "Dice 2: #{d2}"
    d3 = rand(1..6)
    puts "Dice #{d3}"
    tot = d1 + d2 + d3
    puts "Your score is  #{tot}"
    return tot
end☠

puts "Press 1 to play or 2 to leave"
value = gets.chomp
if value == "1"
    s1 = rollDice
    puts "Why it doesnt work :C #{s1}"

elsif value== "2"
    exit
end
```

example session:

```
$ Press 1 to play or 2 to leave
> 1
You roll the dices
Dice 1: 5
Dice 2: 5
Dice 2
Your score is  12
Why it doesnt work :C 12
```

Comment: So yes i have 2 class in the same file, but i still have the error.... i can copy all my file if you want ? i'm a bit lost because this "game" would be so easy for me to code it in Java but in Ruby it's pretty hard
http://www.filedropper.com/projetdes

Comment: please share as a github gist or something like pastebin. Also in Java you cannot define a method in a class and run it from somewhere, you need an instance of it. Probably just add the class "blocks" to your example code so one sees where goes what.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DiGV4nHC, but the method is in the class so i could use it in the class no ? Thank you for the time you're giving to help me

Comment: move all the stuff in the Jeux class that just "floats around" into a method (`def play`?). Then, outside of the class instantiate an object of the class (`jeux = Jeux.new`) and call the method (`jeux.play`). The alternative is to make `roll_dice` a static method (in javas terms): `def self.roll_dice` (instead of `def roll_dice`). I think you have not yet understood ruby Object-Oriented model. And you can put code outside of the classes if you want to have a simple script.

Comment: Dear Felix, thank you for the solution ! Yeah i haven't really understood the ruby coding method for the moment but i'm working on (i did the tutorial on codeacademy and now i try to convert some exercices i did during Java learning into Ruby...) i choosed the method of doing a static method and when all my "game" will work i'll try the first method you told me. 

I wish i could buy you a coffee or something ^^ thank you for all and have a nice day

Comment: I guess I will be in France over Christmas :) ... But coffees are so small there.